# How do I hide a React Native BottomTabNavigator (from React Navigation) on orientation change?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Native app using React Navigation 2.2.5 and a BottomTabNavigator created with createBottomTabNavigator, which has a child StackNavigator. I need the Bottom Navigator to be hidden in landscape orientation globally or in at least one of the screens of the child StackNavigator. Can this even be achieved? Through the style property of the createBottomTabNavigator tabBarOptions?

```
  const RoomStack = createStackNavigator(
{
 Home: {screen: RoomsScreen},
 Room: {screen: RoomsRender},
}, 
{headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
});

const HomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Home: RoomStack,
  'Create a Space': SpaceScreen,
  Settings: SettingsStack,
},
{
  /* Other configuration remains unchanged */
});

export default HomeStack
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom `tabBarComponent` and render null when orientation changed. For receiving event of orientation changed, you can use [React Native Orientation](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation) package (i did not use it myself but i don't think there is problem in using it). Your code will change like this:

```
import myTabBarComponent ...
const HomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
  Home: RoomStack,
  'Create a Space': SpaceScreen,
  Settings: SettingsStack,
},
{
  tabBarComponent: myTabBarComponent,
});
```

And your custom `myTabBarComponent` is:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation';

export default class myTabBarComponent extends React.PureComponent {

  constructor(props: TProps, context: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      lanscape: true,
    }
    Orientation.addOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Orientation.removeOrientationListener(this._orientationDidChange);
  }


  _orientationDidChange = (orientation) => {
    if (orientation === 'LANDSCAPE') {
      this.setState({lanscape : true})
    } else {
      this.setState({lanscape : false})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return !this.state.lanscape ?
      <BottomTabBar {...this.props} />
      :
      <View/>
  }
}
```

Maybe this code is not accurate but the solution is correct because i use it for keyboard show/hide. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was not marked as a correct answer. Worked like a charm :-)